# Numbers.app - cell type "text", "actual", formal" - how to set

Tags: numbers

I had noticed that Numbers.app differs from Excel, in that sometimes it decides a cell is "text" or "actual" or "formula".

Turning a cell into a formula is easy, but changing a cell from "text <-> "actual" seems hard to do, I can't find a menu command or keyboard shortcut, nor has searching here, nor Apple, nor googling.

Long ago, I remember using a keyboard command to force the change, but right now, I'm stuck with a lot of cells that seem to be text, when I need them to be actual.

Comment: Update: One cause of the "text" turns out to be invalid dates... for example if you edit an actual cell's date, so it is invalid (June 31st...) it switches to text.

Comment: In the format sidebar in the cell tab, there is no ‘actual’ per se but you can check the cell data format to see if it is plan text or derived from a formula etc. from the data format drop-down. Is this what you are looking for?